# .Include derived property of partial class?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I have a partial class which returns a derived property:

```
public partial class Consultation
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            string n = string.Empty;
            n += employee.FirstName;
            n += " " + employee.LastName;
            return n;
        }
    } 
}
```

In a business logic layer function I return a List of these entities:

```
using (var Context = new MMEntities())
{

   var cons = Context.Consultations;
   return cons.ToList();

}
```

In a .aspx page I have a databound control which uses the derived property of the entity:

```
DataTextField="Name"
```

However, at compile time I get:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I understand my ObjectContext has been disposed because I've wrapped it in a 'Using' statement.

My question is: How do I include (eager load) the derived Name property in the return method? .Include method only works on navigational properties and I don't want to have long lived ObjectContexts.

Many thanks...

Comment: I can't understand from your code if `employee` is a dependent class of `Consultation`. In this case, I believe you should load it as well. Could you post some more code from `Consultation`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't eager the `Name` property but you must eager load its dependent navigation properties to make it work. So if `employee` in your example is navigation property you must eager load it otherwise your `Name` property will be dependent on lazy loading and living context.

Comment: Thanks! Eager loading the related employee solved the problem.